# Why am I getting SIGTSTP error if I do not initialize variable?

Tags: c++, runtime-error, c++14

While attempting [LECANDY](https://www.codechef.com/problems/LECANDY) problem in codechef, I am getting "**SIGTSTP error - Time limit exceeded**", if I do not initialize variable 'T' to 0 or 1 during its declaration (Line 5).
Also, if I initialize it with any value other than 0 or 1 then it is again giving SIGTSTP error.
As I am taking the value of T as input in the very next line, then why can't I leave it uninitialized during declaration?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int T=0, N,C,element, sum;
    cin>>T;
    
    while(T--)
    {
       sum=0;
       cin>>N>>C;
       
       while(N--)
       {
          cin>>element;
          sum+=element;
       }
       if(sum<=C)
          cout<<"Yes\n";
       else
          cout<<"No\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using uninitialized variables in any way (except to assign to them or otherwise initialize them) leads to *undefined behavior*. Uninitialized variables will have an *indeterminate* value, and it's usually best if you look at them having random or garbage values.

Comment: This sounds like `cin>>T` is failing. Are you sure the first input is a number? (I haven't looked at the problem description.)

Comment: Checking the input routines for success would be a good way to start diagnosing this.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yes, it's a number. This code is working fine as such (if I do not remove '=0' from Line 5).

Comment: @NateEldredge codechef.com does not have any option to view the input set for any problem.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That garbage value of variable T will just be overwritten by the very next statement "cin>>T" (line 6). Then why do we need to bother about it at all before line 6?

Comment: Actually you're right, C++11 promises that the variable will be set to zero if the input fails.  So the initialization value should be irrelevant no matter what, and I don't see any way for any of these variables to be used uninitialized.

Comment: I'm sorry I misread your question. As said, all variables will have a proper value before they're being used. The act of explicitly initializing `T` in the definition should be irrelevant. Unless the competition platform is broken. Or unless the code you use on the competition site is in any way different from the one you show here.